# PHP PDO try catch block not catching

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This PHP PDO try catch block doesn't catch any error. Why is that? did I make a mistake?

```
try {    
    $this->connect();      
    $preparedQuery = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $this->pdo->beginTransaction();
    $preparedQuery->execute();
    $lastInsertId = $this->pdo->lastInsertId();
    $this->pdo->commit();
    return $lastInsertId;

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $this->pdo->rollBack();
    return "error";
}
```

I ran it normally and i get this eror

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function rollBack() on null
```

PDO object

```
private function connect() {
        $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->database . '', $this->username, $this->password);
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
```

Here's my full connection class.

```
class ConnectionModel {

    private $host;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $database;
    private $pdo;

    function __construct() {
        $this->host = 'localhost'; // database server address
        $this->username = 'myuser'; //database server username;
        $this->password = 'mypass'; //database server password;
        $this->database = 'oms1'; //database name
    }

    private function connect() {
        $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->database . '', $this->username, $this->password);
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }


    public function runQuery($sql) {

        try {

            $this->connect();
            $preparedQuery = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
            $this->pdo->beginTransaction();
            $preparedQuery->execute();
            $lastInsertId = $this->pdo->lastInsertId();
            $this->pdo->commit();
            return $lastInsertId;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->pdo->rollBack();
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you set the error mode to exceptions?

Comment: did you mean error_reporting(true) method?

Comment: No, more: `$yourConnectionVariable->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` <- Did you set that? (You don't expect your dog to catch the ball without telling him, *do you*? So you have to tell the dog to catch the ball, otherwise he won't do it. Same goes for PHP)

Comment: yes but not display errors

Comment: Maybe you don't have any errors in your SQL. Please show and explain, why you expect to get an error?

Comment: I changed my database name. But didn't display any error

Comment: Well does your changed database name exists or not?

Comment: ^^ Please add more code and show how your current code looks like, which works. And what you have changed and why you expect it to fail ?

Comment: I'm guessing here, that you don't have error reporting turned on: `ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);` and your connection is silently failing here. But at the rollback your connection was never made and you get a fatal error

Comment: I changed db name to wrong name for check the code.

Comment: Have you turned on error reporting?

Comment: yes. But doesn't it make any sense

Comment: Then please show your **full** and **real** code. (Means your class definition the relevant methods with their full code. How and where you call them) How you use it, where you changed the code and why you expect it to fail and what you expect to get. <- Add this all into your question

Comment: Updated it @Rizier123

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well your problem is, that you don't catch any exceptions for your connection. So you would have to do this:

```
private function connect() {
    try {
        $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->database . '', $this->username, $this->password);
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Right now your call your connection method in a try and catch block, so in your method the connection will throw an Exception, which then gets caught from your try and catch block, which also has the rollBack call in it, but expects the connection to be successful.

If you put your connection call outside of the try and catch block you would get an uncaught Exception:

```
$this->connect();
try {

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    $this->pdo->rollBack();
    return $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As [*@Rizier123* stated in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30585559/php-pdo-try-catch-block-not-catching/30585624#comment49240736_30585559), you need to set your error mode on in PDO:

```
$this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

<sup>[*Read more about PDO Error Modes*](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)</sup>

Now to why you don't get your errors. You are doing the following in your catch:

```
return 'error';
```

That isn't completely useful if you don't get the actual error message.

What you want is to fetch the actual error message:

```
catch (PDOException $e) {
    $this->pdo->rollBack();
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Other than that, we can't tell you much more without seeing your actual SQL Query stored in `$sql`, if you share that, we can help more.

Comment: *unless you're in a function* Since he uses `$this` in his code I'm going to assume, that the code is in a class, which means it has to be in a method(function). So it actually can return something. Also since he returns the last inserted ID, I'm also going to expect, that he's doing something with that return value

Comment: @Rizier123 Just figured that after I wrote it haha! was in the process of editing it! 10 cookies to you :D

Comment: @GRTZ Could you try attempting a `try/catch` when you create your `PDO` object? -> `try{ $this->pdo = new PDO(...); }catch(PDOException $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); }`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the error mode to be exception-based:

```
$this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: And what is if he wrote that, but simply doesn't have an error in his SQL? (You will lose in Russian roulette :)

Comment: I think you played poker here and went ALL IN, but lost everything: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30585559/php-pdo-try-catch-block-not-catching?noredirect=1#comment49240830_30585559

Answer (score 0):

your try/catch block already catch every error.
in this line

```
$this->connect();
```

it fail error, then your code break to catch, so,

```
$this->pdo
```

is still `null` then, in catch block, you try to access `null object`, it fail error again.
you can check `if(isset($this->pdo))` then call `rollBack()` function.